# Modern reporting solutions for distributed data systems

Tags: reporting

We've built a SAAS solution, which has a Frontend in PHP/MySQL. The solution uses our in-house "Backend" API to manage user transactions (financial-ish type of stuff). So basically, some of our data is in the "Frontend" database, while all transactional data is in the "Backend" database.

When it comes to reporting, the Frontend requests transactional reports from the Backend, augments it with Frontend data (user attributes, etc), and draws the report. Usually it's slow and cumbersome to create a new report, and they lack robust features like sorting & filtering. This is partially because there is no single data-source for all the info. Also, we are constantly being asked to provide "adhoc" reporting capabilities - the type of thing that is complex, and has the potential to bring a server to its knees if you aren't careful.

I think we're at the point where we need to invest in a Reporting system, which would be responsible for combining data dumps from Frontend/Backend, and would allow a non-developer to create new reports. One thing that would be important to us is to provide as seamless of an interface as possible to the reports via our Frontend. That might mean the Reporting system exposes web widgets, or perhaps has a web interface that can be accessed with SSO between our system and the Reporting system. In a nutshell, we aren't looking for a dinosaur, we need something modern. Hosted solutions are preferred, but we'd consider something we need to run ourselves. Looking for advice. Thanks!

EDIT: A hosted solution might not work for us. We are located in Canada, and many customers have policies about having data reside in the US (Patriot Act).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting solution. Reports are built using stored procedures, so anyone familiar with SQL will be able to create reports. There is also a built in wizard to get you started quickly. It is also very easy to link reports to each other allowing for easy drill-down style reports.

The solution is very reasonably priced at 129 EUR (~ 170 USD) and can be installed in minutes on any standard web server (PHP being to only requirement).

myDBR can be easily integrated into your existing web-pages via the built-in SSO and styled via CSS to match your sites overall look and feel.